# Process python dictionary based on previous, current and next value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-processing

I have a python dictionary as follows:

```
ip_dict = {'GLArch': {'GLArch-0.png':  ['OTHER', 'Figure 28 TAC '],
                      'GLArch-1.png':  ['DCDFP', 'This insurance '],
                      'GLArch-2.png':  ['DCDNP', 'Item 3'],
                      'GLArch-3.png':  ['OTHER', 'SCHEDULE OF'],
                      'GLArch-4.png':  ['OTHER', 'SCHEDULEed OF3'],
                      'GLArch-5.png':  ['DCCFP', 'COMMERCIAL GENERAL'],
                      'GLArch-6.png':  ['OTHER', 'a The'],
                      'GLArch-7.png':  ['OTHER', 'c Such attorney'],
                      'GLArch-8.png':  ['DCCNP', '2 To any'],
                      'GLArch-9.png':  ['OTHER', 'e as part'],
                      'GLArch-10.png': ['OTHER', '1 A watercraft'],
                      'GLArch-11.png': ['OTHER', '5 That particular'],
                      'GLArch-12.png': ['DCCNP', 'Damages claimed'],
                      'GLArch-13.png': ['OTHER', 'resulting from the'],
                      'GLArch-14.png': ['DCCNP', 'processing or packaging'],
                      'GLArch-15.png': ['DCCNP', 's. Fungi'],
                      'GLArch-16.png': ['OTHER', '1 the actual'],
                      'GLArch-17.png': ['OTHER', '5 6 9 10 11']}}
```

I want to process it such that if there is one or more `OTHER` appearing in between `DCCFP` and `DCCNP` or if there is one or more `OTHER` appearing in between `DCCNP` and another `DCCNP` then it should be renamed to `DCCNP`. So in the element `GLArch-6.png` and `GLArch-7.png`, since they both are appearing in between `DCCFP` and `DCCNP`, the `OTHER` present in the list will be renamed to `DCCNP`. Similary `GLArch-9.png`, `GLArch-10.png` and `GLArch-11.png`, the `OTHER` present in them will be renamed to `DCCNP` because these elements lie in between `DCCNP` and another `DCCNP`. Same goes for `GLArch-13.png`. So the output dictionary would look like:

```
op_dict = {'GLArch': {'GLArch-0.png':  ['OTHER', 'Figure 28 TAC '],
                      'GLArch-1.png':  ['DCDFP', 'This insurance '],
                      'GLArch-2.png':  ['DCDNP', 'Item 3'],
                      'GLArch-3.png':  ['OTHER', 'SCHEDULE OF'],
                      'GLArch-4.png':  ['OTHER', 'SCHEDULEed OF3'],
                      'GLArch-5.png':  ['DCCFP', 'COMMERCIAL GENERAL'],
                      'GLArch-6.png':  ['DCCNP', 'a The'],
                      'GLArch-7.png':  ['DCCNP', 'c Such attorney'],
                      'GLArch-8.png':  ['DCCNP', '2 To any'],
                      'GLArch-9.png':  ['DCCNP', 'e as part'],
                      'GLArch-10.png': ['DCCNP', '1 A watercraft'],
                      'GLArch-11.png': ['DCCNP', '5 That particular'],
                      'GLArch-12.png': ['DCCNP', 'Damages claimed'],
                      'GLArch-13.png': ['DCCNP', 'resulting from the'],
                      'GLArch-14.png': ['DCCNP', 'processing or packaging'],
                      'GLArch-15.png': ['DCCNP', 's. Fungi'],
                      'GLArch-16.png': ['OTHER', '1 the actual'],
                      'GLArch-17.png': ['OTHER', '5 6 9 10 11']}}
```

I tried the below script but it is not working:

```
def process_dict(ip_dict):
    op_dict = {}
    for key, value in ip_dict.items():
        op_dict[key] = {}
        prev_val = None

        for k, v in value.items():
            if prev_val is not None and ("DCCFP" in prev_val and "DCCNP" in v[0]):
                op_dict[key][k] = ["DCCFP", v[1]]
            else:
                op_dict[key][k] = v

            prev_val = v[0]

    return op_dict
```

Comment: What about the keys `DCDFP` and `DCDNP`? Should they be considered?

Comment: @lowkey Only need to focus on `DCCFP` and `DCCNP` and `OTHER`.

Comment: You are never entering the if branch. The reason is that `("DCCFP" in prev_val and "DCCNP" in v[0])` checks if "DCCFP" and "DCCNP" are following each other.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a temporary list to hold the OTHER items while waiting to know how to handle them. Using a function here to be able to generalize on a nested dictionary.

```
def process(d):
    start_set = {'DCCFP', 'DCCNP'}
    end_set = {'DCCNP'}

    last = 'OTHER'
    out = {}
    tmp = []
    for k, l in d.items():
        #print(k, flag, l, tmp)
        if l[0] in start_set:      # if START, set name
            last = l[0]
        if l[0] == 'OTHER':        # if OTHER, collect
            tmp.append([k, l[1:]])
            continue
        if l[0] not in end_set:   # if not END keep "OTHER" name
            last = 'OTHER'
        for k2, v in tmp:         # append collected values
            out[k2] = [last, *v]
        tmp = []                  # reset tmp list
        out[k] = l[:]             # add current non-OTHER

    for k, v in tmp:              # handle final items if any
        out[k] = ['OTHER', *v]
    return out

final_out = {k: process(d) for k,d in ip_dict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'GLArch': {'GLArch-0.png': ['OTHER', 'Figure 28 TAC '],
            'GLArch-1.png': ['DCDFP', 'This insurance '],
            'GLArch-2.png': ['DCDNP', 'Item 3'],
            'GLArch-3.png': ['OTHER', 'SCHEDULE OF'],
            'GLArch-4.png': ['OTHER', 'SCHEDULEed OF3'],
            'GLArch-5.png': ['DCCFP', 'COMMERCIAL GENERAL'],
            'GLArch-6.png': ['DCCNP', 'a The'],
            'GLArch-7.png': ['DCCNP', 'c Such attorney'],
            'GLArch-8.png': ['DCCNP', '2 To any'],
            'GLArch-9.png': ['DCCNP', 'e as part'],
            'GLArch-10.png': ['DCCNP', '1 A watercraft'],
            'GLArch-11.png': ['DCCNP', '5 That particular'],
            'GLArch-12.png': ['DCCNP', 'Damages claimed'],
            'GLArch-13.png': ['DCCNP', 'resulting from the'],
            'GLArch-14.png': ['DCCNP', 'processing or packaging'],
            'GLArch-15.png': ['DCCNP', 's. Fungi'],
            'GLArch-16.png': ['OTHER', '1 the actual'],
            'GLArch-17.png': ['OTHER', '5 6 9 10 11']}}
```

Comment: The last line makes me uncomfortable as I won't be knowing the key. There may be multiple keys or one and I won't have knowledge about them beforehand.

Comment: @spectre can you clarify? That's probably easy to adapt but you failed to explain how this should generalize. Check the update to use a function as I initially suggested.

Answer (score 0):

My answer uses the same basic technique as @mozway, but it modifies the dict in-place, which makes it a bit simpler. If you need to preserve `ip_dict`, you can create a deepcopy first (using [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)) and process the copy.

```
START_TOKENS = {"DCCFP", "DCCNP"}
END_TOKENS = {"DCCNP"}

def process_dict_inplace(ip_dict):
    for inner_dict in ip_dict.values():
        others_to_change = None

        for name, (kind, _) in inner_dict.items():
            # others_to_change is None until the first occurrence of a START_TOKEN
            if others_to_change is not None:
                if kind == "OTHER":
                    others_to_change.append(name)
                    continue

                if kind in END_TOKENS:
                    for other in others_to_change:
                        inner_dict[other][0] = "DCCNP"

            if kind in START_TOKENS:
                others_to_change = []
```